# How to check for falsy, when using JSON.stringify on an empty user input

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, validation

`req.body["test"]` will be empty  or will have an value, but before working with it I will JSON.stringify that value, because of malicous code that could be send from a user.

But now I can not check that string that easy like checking for falsy value.

For example, if I get an empty string, and then check for an empty user input:

```
//will give an error it is like  'var c="""";' of course this doesn't work.
    var checking=JSON.stringify(req.body["test"]) // has value """"
         If(checking)//check falsy
```

Comment: why not test `eq.body["test"].length > 0` before ?

Comment: What about `var checking = req.body.test ? JSON.stringify(req.body.test) : null` ?

Answer (score 1):

Just don't convert it to JSON.

At least, don't convert it to JSON before testing to see if it is falsy.

There is nothing that `req.body.test` could contain that would do any harm if you put in `if (HERE)`.

On a wider scope, you should take *appropriate* measures to sanitise / escape data based on *what you are going to do with it*. Converting to JSON creates problems and doesn't solve all security problems.

Comment: Ok, but I am using Node.js, "req.body" has automatially the JSON - format.

Comment: @user254197 — You seem to be confusing the JSON data format with JavaScript data types.